# Python/Numpy - Speeding up Monte Carlo method for radioactive decay

Tags: python, performance, numpy, montecarlo

I am trying to optimize the generation of decay times for a radioactive isotope Monte Carlo. 
That is given `nsims` atoms of an isotope with a halflife of `t12`, when does each isotope decay?
I tried to optimize this by generating random numbers for all un-decayed atoms at once using a single `numpy.random.random` call (I call this method parallel), but I hope that there is still more performance to be gained. I also show a method that does this calculation for each isotope individually (serial).

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize

t12 = 3.1*60.
dt = 0.01
ln2 = np.log(2)
decay_exp = lambda t,A,tau: A * np.exp(-t/tau)

def serial(nsims):
    sim_start_time = time.clock()
    decay_time = np.zeros(nsims)
    for i in range(nsims):
        t = dt
        while decay_time[i] == 0:
            if np.random.random() > np.exp(-ln2*dt/t12):
                decay_time[i] = t
            t += dt
    sim_end_time = time.clock()
    return (sim_end_time - sim_start_time,decay_time)

def parallel(nsims):
    sim_start_time = time.clock()
    decay_time = np.zeros(nsims)
    t = dt
    while 0 in decay_time:
        inot_decayed = np.where(decay_time == 0)[0]
        idecay_check = np.random.random(len(inot_decayed)) > np.exp(-ln2*dt/t12)
        decay_time[inot_decayed[np.where(idecay_check==True)[0]]] = t
        t += dt
    sim_end_time = time.clock()
    return (sim_end_time - sim_start_time,decay_time)
```

I'm interested in any suggestions that performs better than the `parallel` function that is pure python, i.e. not cython. 
This method already improves greatly upon the `serial` method of calculating this for large `nsims`.

[image: The performance gain of parallel vs serial functions, is there a better method?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still some speed gains to be had from your original "parallel" (vectorized is the correct word) execution.

Remark, this is micro-management, but it does still give a small performance increase.

```
import numpy as np
t12 = 3.1*60.
dt = 0.01
ln2 = np.log(2)

s = 98765

def parallel(nsims):  # your code, unaltered, except removed inaccurate timing method
    decay_time = np.zeros(nsims)
    t = dt
    np.random.seed(s) # also had to add a seed to get comparable results
    while 0 in decay_time:
        inot_decayed = np.where(decay_time == 0)[0]
        idecay_check = np.random.random(len(inot_decayed)) > np.exp(-ln2*dt/t12)
        decay_time[inot_decayed[np.where(idecay_check==True)[0]]] = t
        t += dt
    return decay_time

def parallel_micro(nsims): # micromanaged code
    decay_time = np.zeros(nsims)
    t = dt
    half_time = np.exp(-ln2*dt/t12)  # there was no need to calculate this again in every loop iteration
    np.random.seed(s)  # fixed seed to get comparable results
    while 0 in decay_time:
        inot_decayed = np.where(decay_time == 0)[0]  # only here you need the call to np.where
        # to my own surprise, len(some_array) is quicker than some_array.size (function lookup vs attribute lookup)
        idecay_check = np.random.random(len(inot_decayed)) > half_time
        decay_time[inot_decayed[idecay_check]] = t # no need for another np.where and certainly not for another boolean comparison
        t += dt
    return decay_time
```

You can run timing measurements with the [timeit module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). Profiling will tell you that the bottleneck here is the call to `np.where`.

Knowing that the bottleneck is `np.where`, you could get rid of it like this:

```
def parallel_micro2(nsims):
    decay_time = np.zeros(nsims)
    t = dt
    half_time = np.exp(-ln2*dt/t12)
    np.random.seed(s)
    indices = np.where(decay_time==0)[0]
    u = len(indices)
    while u:
        decayed = np.random.random(u) > half_time
        decay_time[indices[decayed]] = t
        indices = indices[np.logical_not(decayed)]
        u = len(indices)
        t += dt
    return decay_time
```

And that does give a rather large speed increase:

```
In [2]: %timeit -n1 -r1 parallel_micro2(1e4)
1 loops, best of 1: 7.81 s per loop

In [3]: %timeit -n1 -r1 parallel_micro(1e4)
1 loops, best of 1: 29 s per loop

In [4]: %timeit -n1 -r1 parallel(1e4)
1 loops, best of 1: 33.5 s per loop
```

Don't forget to get rid of the call to `np.random.seed` when you're done optimizing.